# What is a generalized uncurry function in Scheme, for a curry function of n parameter?

Tags: recursion, scheme, currying

I am pretty new to Scheme, and I am trying to devise a more generalized uncurry function in Scheme. I am trying to have it take in a curried function with "n" parameters, and return the result of applying said function to all parameters at once. So something like `((uncurry (curry +)) 1 2 3)` might return `6`.

Comment: A major problem with this is that `(curry +)` isn't really a curried function; `(((curry +) 1) 2) 3)`doesn't work. It's more a function that takes some arguments and produces a variadic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic `uncurry` can be written to call a function, `f`, with arguments, `t`, one at a time -

```scm
(define ((uncurry f) . t)
  (if (null? t)
      f
      (apply (uncurry (f (car t)))
             (cdr t))))
```

Using it on `(curry +)` will not work because `+` is a *variadic* function. However, for functions of known arity, it works just fine -

```scm
(define (plus a b c)
  (+ a b c))

((uncurry (curry plus)) 1 2 3)       ; 6
```

If you don't supply all three arguments, the "remainder" of the curried function will be returned -

```scm
(((uncurry (curry plus)) 1 2) 3)     ; 6
((((uncurry (curry plus)) 1) 2) 3)   ; 6
(((((uncurry (curry plus))) 1) 2) 3) ; 6
```

Subsequent calls to `uncurry` could be used if additional arguments need to be supplied at a later time -

```scm
((uncurry ((uncurry (curry plus)) 1)) 2 3) ; 6
```

However, if you try to apply too many arguments, a run time error will be raised -

```scm
((uncurry (curry plus)) 1 2 3 4)     ; error, expected procedure; 6 given
```

> *Is there a way to perform a generalized uncurry function on curried, variadic functions? That was what the question was referring to with "generalized", needs to be able to work on a variable number of arguments.*

I recommend you see molbdnilo's comment on your question. You cannot effectively `curry` a variadic function like `+` because currying is the abstraction of arity. To put this another way, if `+` can take 0 to infinite arguments, how many applied arguments should `(curry +)` take before it returns a sum rather than a function?

Maybe you are looking for `partial` application?

```scm
(define ((partial f . a) . b)
  (apply f (append a b)))
```

```scm
((partial + 1 2)) ; 3
((partial + 1) 2) ; 3
((partial +) 1 2) ; 3
```

Comment: Is there a way to perform a generalized uncurry function on curried, variadic functions?

Comment: That was what the question was referring to with "generalized", needs to be able to work on a variable number of arguments.

Comment: I updated my answer in attempt to clear this up for you